# Автоматические активные табы

Tags: jquery, tabs

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs a').click(function(){
        switch_tabs(jQuery(this));
});
switch_tabs(jQuery('.defaulttab'));
});
function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    jQuery('.tab-content').hide();
    jQuery('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");
    jQuery('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
}</script>


                 <ul class="tabs">
    [xfgiven_lost]<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel = "tab-1" class = "defaulttab">Лостфильм</a></li>[/xfgiven_lost]
    [xfgiven_bab]<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel = "tab-2">Бабайко</a></li>[/xfgiven_bab]
    [xfgiven_new]<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel = "tab-3">Ньюстудио</a></li>[/xfgiven_new]
    [xfgiven_sub]<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel = "tab-4">Субтитры</a></li>[/xfgiven_sub]
</ul>
[xfgiven_lost]<div class = "tab-content" id = "tab-1"><iframe  rel="nofollow" src="[xfvalue_lost]" width="600" height="370" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>[/xfgiven_lost]
[xfgiven_bab]<div class = "tab-content" id = "tab-2"><iframe  rel="nofollow" src="[xfvalue_bab]" width="600" height="370" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>[/xfgiven_bab]
[xfgiven_new]<div class = "tab-content" id = "tab-3"><iframe  rel="nofollow" src="[xfvalue_new]" width="600" height="370" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>[/xfgiven_new]
[xfgiven_sub]<div class = "tab-content" id = "tab-4"><iframe  rel="nofollow" src="[xfvalue_sub]" width="600" height="370" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>[/xfgiven_sub]
```

Скажите пожалуйста, что нужно изменить или дописать, что бы первый ТАБ в котором есть содержимое отображался автоматом а не только по клику, независимо от того стоит он первый, пятый или десятый.

При загрузке странички: Таб 3 отображается так.
http://firepic.org/images/2015-03/09/z2k742du3uox.png
При клике на него вот так:
http://firepic.org/images/2015-03/09/9g2x5q8v836d.png
И нужно что бы при загрузке было так если в каком-то табе есть контент.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде дефолтный таб жестко прописан, как .defaulttab. Возможно, он уже определен как дефолтный на стороне сервера. Вам нужно либо определить в каком случае ставится класс .defaulttab у таба на стороне сервера, либо переписать строку switch_tabs(jQuery('.defaulttab')); на стороне клиента.

По представленному вами куску кода не понятно, как именно работает ваша система

Comment: Да этот код стоит на сайте только в фуллстори, при чем тут сервер? :)

Comment: Откуда мне знать. Вы не привели по крайней мере html код, который выдает сервер, чтобы быть точно уверенным. Если у таба в коде на сервере выставляется класс .defaulttab, то вам определенно нужно смотреть в сторону сервера, и делать изменения там. И что за фулстори?

Comment: Меня интерисует только, что вместо switch_tabs(jQuery('.defaulttab'));   написать, что бы открывался "первый таб в котором есть содержимое",  а то по дефолту, открывается дефолтный таб. Но есть новости на сайте где нет содержимого в первом дефолтном табе,  таб с активным содержимым показывается, но его содержимое нет, только по клику например на третий таб который местит содержимое он его покажет.

Comment: Содержимое например есть в Табе номер 3, в табе дефолт номер 1 нет содержимого, сайт своими силами его не показывает, а показывает тайтл таба 3, но без содержимого, что бы посмотреть содержимое, нужно кликнуть :(

Comment: Что вы ожидаете в качестве ответа-помощи? Если конкретно какой-то код, то вы не представили html код, который выдает сервер. Я не смогу помочь вам основываясь только на вашем словесном описании проблемы. По вашему текущему описанию проблемы я могу лишь сказать, что вам нужно смотреть в сторону сервера.

Comment: Выложил весь код, но не хочет сайт форматировать в теги "код" после редактирования, прийдется в нотепад ставить.